Native macOS Text Replacement (adding records)
I found a 2020 year script on the Internet, with which you can create pairs (key value) in the keyboard settings text replacement
Here's the source
Here's the script
use AppleScript version "2.4" -- Yosemite (10.10) or later
use scripting additions

set theWord to the clipboard as text

tell application id "com.apple.systempreferences"
  reveal anchor "Text" of pane id "com.apple.preference.keyboard"
  activate
end tell

tell application id "com.apple.systemevents"
  tell application process "System Preferences"
    tell window "Keyboard"
      tell tab group 1
        tell group 1
          tell button 1
            click
            --delay 0.5
          end tell
        end tell
        tell scroll area 1
          tell table 1
            tell row -1
              tell UI element 1
                tell text field 1
                  set value to theWord
                  --confirm
                end tell
              end tell
              tell UI element 2
                tell text field 1
                  set value to theWord
                  set focused to true
                end tell
              end tell
            end tell
          end tell
        end tell
      end tell
    end tell
  end tell
end tell

But it doesn't work, I get an error Unable to get pane id "com.apple.preference.keyboard"
Does anyone have a working version? I would be very grateful!

GUI scripting is dependent on the version you are using, as Apple (or any developer) is free to rename and/or rearrange their UI hierarchy as they want.  For example, in macOS Sonoma the System Settings Keyboard pane id is com.apple.Keyboard-Settings.extension and the anchor is named TextReplacements.

@red_menace Thank you very much I managed to open the text replacement settings, but now I get the following error Received an error from «System Events»: Unable to get application process "System Preferences".

The name is no longer "System Preferences", it is now "System Settings".

@red_menace I tried to replace it and I get this error «System Settings»: REVEAL_ANCHOR_ERR_MODAL

GUI scripting is fragile, and depends a lot on the particular layout of the user interface, which can change with new application and OS versions.  Your linked script would be for Catalina or Big Sur, but there have been a few OS upgrades since then.  Apple tends to rearrange things, so the UI hierarchy of the System Preferences/Settings application would need to be explored to get the new layout, which in this case is completely different and uses sheets.
Another option would be to use the preference pane URL scheme.  A bit of GUI scripting is still needed, but it can just be keystrokes for navigating the sheets.
The following script contains handlers that use both approaches for adding text replacements - note that depending on your particular setup you may need to adjust the delays (for example, the REVEAL_ANCHOR_ERR_MODAL error is from trying to reveal an anchor while a modal dialog/sheet is still open):
on run -- examples (macOS 14 Sonoma)
   try
      textReplacementWithGUI("testing", "one, two, three")
      textReplacementWithURLScheme("another", "whatever")
   on error errmess
      log errmess
   end try
   # tell application "System Settings" to quit
end run

on textReplacementWithGUI(replaceText, withText) -- text replacements via GUI scripting (English)
   tell application "System Settings" -- reveal target window and activate
      reveal anchor "TextReplacements" of pane id "com.apple.Keyboard-Settings.extension"
      delay 0.5 -- give the window time to set up
      activate
   end tell
   tell application "System Events"
      tell application process "System Settings" to tell window 1 to tell sheet 1 -- initial replacements sheet
         tell group 1 to tell scroll area 1 to tell group 1 to click button 1 -- the add (+) button
         delay 0.25 -- give the second sheet time to appear
         tell sheet 1 to tell group 1 to tell scroll area 1 to tell group 1 -- now in the add sheet
            set value of text field "Replace" to replaceText
            tell text field "With"
               set focused to true
               set value to withText
            end tell
            keystroke return -- dismiss the add sheet (default button)
         end tell
      end tell
      delay 0.25
      keystroke return -- dismiss the replacements sheet
   end tell
   delay 0.25 -- give sheets time to close
end textReplacementWithGUI

on textReplacementWithURLScheme(replaceText, withText) -- text replacements via preference pane URL scheme
   set isRunning to running of application "System Settings"
   do shell script "open \"x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.Keyboard-Settings.extension?TextReplacements\"" -- initial replacements sheet
   if not isRunning then delay 0.5
   tell application "System Settings" to activate
   delay 0.5
   tell application "System Events"
      if isRunning then keystroke tab -- move to the add (+) button
      keystroke space -- bring up add dialog
      delay 0.25
      keystroke replaceText -- Replace
      keystroke tab -- move to the next text field
      keystroke withText -- With
      keystroke return -- dismiss add sheet
      delay 0.25
      keystroke return -- dismiss replacements sheet
   end tell
   delay 0.25 -- give sheets time to close
end textReplacementWithURLScheme


Thank you, it works perfectly, only I changed the delay for me
